# Smileys couldn't displayed within text box php codeigniter

Tags: php

I 've used the below code to convert text to emoticons in javascript,

```
function add_smile($text) {
    var $text=$text;
    function RegExpEscape(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"); 
}

var emoticons = {
    ':)'         : 'images/smileys/angry.gif',
    ':('         : 'images/smileys/sad.gif',
    ';)'         : 'images/smileys/wink.gif'
}

var result =$text;
var emotcode;
var regex;

for (emotcode in emoticons)
{
    regex = new RegExp(RegExpEscape(emotcode), 'gi');
    result = result.replace(regex, function(match) {
        var pic = emoticons[match.toLowerCase()];

        if (pic != undefined) {
              return '<img src="' + pic + '"/>';
        } else {
            return match;
        }
    });
}
    $('#editor-textarea').val($('#editor-textarea').val() + " " + result);
}
```

In my view,

```
<textarea name="content" class="editor-textarea" id="editor-textarea">
</textarea>

<?php foreach($smiles as $k=>$v) : ?>
    <button type="button" class="nobutton" onclick="add_smile('<?php echo $k ?>')"><?php echo $v ?></button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The javascript function now replace the text with `<img src="images/smileys/angry.gif">` as text not display as  image.How do I solve this?

Comment: How can I solve this?Can anybody answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how textarea works - it displays and allows you to edit text. If you need a WYSIWYG control, think of using `contentEditable` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

```js
$("button.make-editable").on("click", function() {
  $("#inputbox")
    .attr('contenteditable', 'true')
    .html("<b>this is bold</b>this is smiley \
            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/SNice.svg' />");

});


$("button.make-standard").on("click", function() {
  var inputbox = $("#inputbox");

  inputbox.attr('contenteditable', 'false');
  console.log(inputbox.html());

});
```

```css
#inputbox {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#inputbox img {
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputbox">
  This text should become editable.
</div>

<button class='make-editable'>Make DIV editable</button>
<button class='make-standard'>Remove "contentEditable", get value</button>
```

Comment: It also gives the same result!! `<div class="editor-textarea-part"><textarea name="content" class="editor-textarea" id="editor-textarea"></div>`.In js `$('#editor-textarea').val($('#editor-textarea').val() + " " + result);`

Comment: you don't set the `.val()`, but rather `.html()` for items with editable content.

Comment: Thanks for the code How can I apply this for multiple emojis?Like Any shortcodes?